# Hadoop map-Reduce program not runing

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm new to Hadoop MapReduce. When I'm trying to run my MapReduce code using the following command:

```
vishal@XXXX bin/hadoop jar /user/vishal/WordCount com.WordCount.java /user/vishal/file01 /user/vishal/output.
```

It displays the following output:

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error opening job jar: /user/vishal/WordCount.jar     
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:130)          
    Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file    
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)     
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:131)    
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:150)    
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:87)    
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:128)
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

Your command is asking Hadoop to run a JAR but is specifying a directory instead.

You have also added '.java' to the class name, which is not required. (This is assuming you have written the package name, `com.WordCount`, correctly).

First build the jar in `/user/vishal/WordCount.jar` (ensure this is a local directory, not HDFS) then run the command without the '.java' at the end of the class name. Also, you put a dot at the end of the command in your question, I hope that isn't there in the real command.

```
bin/hadoop jar /user/vishal/WordCount.jar com.WordCount /user/vishal/file01 /user/vishal/output
```

See the [Hadoop tutorial's 'Usage' section](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.20.2/mapred_tutorial.html#Usage) for more.

Comment: are we supposed to keep our jar in HDFS directory or in the normal directory where our haddop is installed

Comment: I think the JAR needs to be on your local machine's filesystem rather than HDFS. Are you sure the JAR file exists as you are referring to it (same spelling, capitalisation)?

Comment: so i need to store the jar file in our local system and then run the same command???

Comment: Yes, try that (don't forget to adjust the JAR path in the command)